# preciso adicionar os itens do primeiro if em uma lista mas nao entendi como fazer isso, alguém com conhecimento mais avançado pode ajudar?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        
        String nome = "";
        String email = "";
        int contato;
        contato = 0;
        int idade;
        idade = 0;
        int opcao;
        opcao = 0;
        
        //inicio do menu
        System.out.println("--Bem vindo--");
        System.out.println("1 para cadastrar novo usuario");
        System.out.println("2 para listar usuarios cadastrados");
        System.out.println("Selecione a opcao: ");
        
        Scanner lerOpcao = new Scanner(System.in); //le a opcao desejada pelo usuario
        opcao = lerOpcao.nextInt();
        
        //se a opcao selecionada no menu for 1 entra nesse bloco de codigo
        if (opcao==1);
            System.out.println("Voce selecionou o menu de cadastros em Java.");
            System.out.println("Digite o nome a ser cadastrado: ");
            Scanner lerNome = new Scanner(System.in);
            nome = lerNome.next();
            System.out.println("Digite o email a ser cadastrado: ");
            Scanner lerEmail = new Scanner(System.in);
            email = lerEmail.next();
            System.out.println("Digite o contato a ser cadastrado: ");
            Scanner lerContato = new Scanner(System.in);
            contato = lerContato.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite a idade a ser cadastrada: ");
            Scanner lerIdade = new Scanner(System.in);
            idade = lerIdade.nextInt();
            
            
    } 
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

não sei se entendi bem o seu problema, mas se entendi, a melhor opção seria você criar uma classe para receber esses elementos e guarda-los em uma lista, mais ou menos assim:

Crie uma classe com os atributos, exemplo:

```
public class Usuario {
private String nome;
private String email;
private Integer contato;
private Integer idade;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Integer getContato() {
    return contato;
}

public void setContato(Integer contato) {
    this.contato = contato;
}

public Integer getIdade() {
    return idade;
}

public void setIdade(Integer idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}
}
```

Antes do if você cria a lista, dentro do if você cria uma instancia da classe que criou acima e vai setando os valores dos campos de acordo com as entradas no console, você não precisa instanciar um Scanner para cada input, pode utilizar a mesma instancia para leitura dos dados:

```
List<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<>();    
if(opcao == 1) {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Voce selecionou o menu de cadastros em Java.");
    System.out.println("Digite o nome a ser cadastrado: ");
    usuario.setNome(sc.next());
    System.out.println("Digite o email a ser cadastrado: ");
    usuario.setEmail(sc.next());
    System.out.println("Digite o contato a ser cadastrado: ");
    usuario.setContato(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Digite a idade a ser cadastrada: ");
    usuario.setIdade(sc.nextInt());
    lista.add(usuario);
}
```

os dados ficarão armazenados na lista, essa lista contém objetos Usuario.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, ajudou muito mesmo.

Comment: Opa, legal, que bom!